# The command dsc (Azure BridgeToKubernetes) is failing when running on Git Bash or Windows CMD but working on WSL in isolation mode

Tags: remote-debugging, dsc

The command dsc (BridgeToKubernetes) is failing when running on Git Bash or Windows CMD but working on WSL in isolation mode and working in non-isolation mode. I am connecting to the remote cluster hosted on OCI OKE.

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvEy2.png)

It should work on Windows CMD too